# how to display name of a particular code from a javascript object in angular js and html5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a angular controller that has the following array which has 3 values.

```
controller.medicalInstitues;
```

I want to take the 4th object in the array with code "AUS". Then further, I want to display the name of only 2 medical institutes with the code as "SYD" and "MEL" within that choosen bject from the parent array.

something like below:

```
var country = select controller.medicalInstitues.countryCode = "AUS"
var institues = select controller.medicalInstitues.name from country.code="SYD" and "MEL";

now I need to bind these in the UI (Angular).

<span class="code"> {{ controller.institutes.name }}</span>
```

Comment: Please, provide any code, also are you sure that always will have 4 objects with code "AUS"?

Comment: @developer033: Yes, it has an array of 4 objects. I want ONLY the 4th object whose code is AUS. And in that object, I have so many properties where I have code and name. I want to display names where code is SYd and MEL alone as it has many other codes too.

Comment: Provide your code and we can help.

Comment: @developer033: Thank you so much for your kind note, as it is a government project, I am restricted to use that code here, but my simple question is, I am looking for the syntax for displaying values of an ID. That's all. It should be in Angular html5. Please help me

Comment: I mean the structure man... we can't help without see at least a piece of your structure.

Comment: @developer033: Thank you so much again. I am looking for something like what Stephen wrote. Just a niggle in the code part I didn't understand or not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have got your list of values in medicalInstitues, then in the angularjs controller you can do

```
$scope.institues = medicalInstitues.filter(function(value){
    return value.countryCode == "AUS" && (value.code == "SYD" || value.code == "MEL");
});
```

In HTML you can use ng-repeat:

```
<div controller="controller">
    ....
    <span ng-repeat="institue in institues">{{institue.name}}</span>
    ....
</div>
```

Comment: thank you I am using your approach, but what is class code? I want only two codes' names as "Sydney" and "Melbourne" where the codes are SYD and MEL respectively. It has many codes such as CAN, SYD, MEL,BRB etc.

Comment: Your answer is almost close but I want to apply pipe or filter by code, i.e to display only the names of code I want

Comment: @Learner Answer updated. The code in class is just a css as it is in your post.

Comment: @Learner you might want to check out this if you haven't: https://www.codecademy.com/en/courses/learn-angularjs/lessons/your-first-app

Comment: thank you, again its very close except for two issues. 1) value has 6 objects and those objects have code and name. So basically its an array of 6 objects in value, so value.code becomes undefined. How to rectify this? 2) I don't need to write values using ng-repeat because, I need each "name" to be set in different place. So I think I can do something like filter/pipe and check? How to do it

Comment: thank you very much, I acheived what I want, except for some niggle of displaying the value. I am confident to solve it. Cheers

Comment: @Learner that's great!

Comment: Your approach pretty much helped me a lot. I could make it, its all good now, thank you so much again.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, to bind the 4th object in your array you can set:

$scope.AUS = yourArray[3]

Then in the html you can show the object properties:

{{ AUS."object path to name" }}

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understood your question well, you can do the following:

```
// If you have an array that you already know that will come 4 items with the same country code, you can simply do:
$scope.medicalInstitues = array[3];

// Otherwise:
$scope.medicalInstitues = array.filter(function (value) {
  return value.countryCode == "AUS";
})[3];

// To get all 'institues' with the countryCode equals to 'SYD' or 'MEL':
$scope.institues = array.filter(function (value) {
  return value.countryCode == "SYD" || value.countryCode == "MEL";
});
```

Comment: I didn't understand, what? We all here are like blind people trying to discover what you want since you didn't provide a line of code. Please explain what you want.